# How to get list to time zone abbreviations in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, momentjs, timezone-offset

I'm writing a date-related logic where the timezone name is important. The user enters the time whatever they want and the timestamp then gets converted to the timezone mentioned internally in a variable.
Example - A time entered in IST (GMT +5.30) should be converted to EDT (GMT -5).
So far everything is going well. What happened recently is when daylight saving stopped in Eastern time my logic failed as it was taking EST. I tried writing `EDT` but was getting an error that EDT is not supported. After some research, I found writing `EST5EDT` fixed my problem of daylight conversion.

Is there any list where I can get the list of abbreviations including the daylight toggling names also?

I found a link for [timezones](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/mq-appliance/9.1?topic=commands-name) which has the `EST5EDT` string but I am not able to find any official documentation for the Date API.

Comment: I'm not sure that the resource you are looking for exists, anyway, please have a look to [timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) description page that suggest to avoid timezone abbreviation for conversions and business logic

Comment: the problem is AS400 (IBM i) systems aren't able to fetch timezone identifier. they can only send offset and the abbreviation. this is causing error as they are sending Eastern as EDT/EST and EDT isn't supported by Date API.

Comment: Then you have a fundamental problem. Different locations switch between these different offsets at different times. That’s why you can only really use *locations* like `America/New_York` for this, not specific offsets.

Comment: @avishekdr - your question only asks about JavaScript.  What does AS400 have to do with it?  If you're doing something beyond JS in the browser or Node.JS, you should expand your question to include those details and tag appropriately.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that time zone abbreviations are not unique in the general case.  For example, the "I" in "IST" can stand for India, Israel, or Ireland.  However, when you're talking about `EST5EDT` - that's not an abbreviation.  That's a POSIX `TZ` string.  You can read more in the section titled "POSIX style time zones", towards the bottom of the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: Hey Matt, actually AS400's system timezone is stored in DB2 which I use through an api for some conversion stuffs

Comment: Civil timezone names are not standardised. The only support in ECMAScript is the optional implementation dependent name in the output of [*toString*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-timezoneestring). Support for ECMA-402 via [*Intl.DateTimeFormat*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) provides support for offsets using [IANA representative locations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), but there is no support for parsing or otherwise using civil timezone names or abbreviations.